# Redirecting to my page

Tags: facebook, authentication, redirect

I have ASP.Net application, and want users to access it from facebook via IFRAME

Application is located at:
facebook.tk-osmica.hr/

My setup: (leading http removed to avoid stackoverflow restrictions)
Canvas URL: facebook.tk-osmica.hr/
Canvas Page: apps.facebook.com/dankotestd (raedonly)

in my web.config i did setup API Key and secret, 
and "PostAuthorizeRedirectURL=Default.aspx"

i'm getting error:

```
   "error": 
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
```

I was forwarded to URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=244980988904443&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/dankotest2/Default.aspx&scope=user_photos

I guess I should have been redirected to:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=244980988904443&redirect_uri=http://facebook.tk-osmica.hr/Default.aspx&scope=user_photos

but i can't set it up to do so.

What is right configuration?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a canvas (iframed) app, or a web page that has facebook functionality?  If you're building a canvas app, then being redirected to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=244980988904443&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/dankotest2/Default.aspx&scope=user_photos was correct.  Because your canvas app will live at http://apps.facebook.com/dankotest2/Default.aspx.

Comment: I am building IFRAME app.
Why am i getting this error message then?

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue in the app settings.

Comment: yes, you can see my Canvas URL and Canvas page, what else should be configured (bedides API Key and secret) ?